# Where can I find Magento 2 product view page?

Tags: magento2, product

I want to change my product list view. But I can't find the file . I used sm himarket theme anyone have idea where I need to change?

Comment: Check once this file->app/design/frontend/YourTheme/YourPackage/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: Maybe strange but I cant find the Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes Magento 2 2 6 I see only ADVANCED
->Admin
->System

Comment: Hi, please dont put questions in the answer section/.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145405)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin panel:

For Front End:

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront > Yes

---

And refresh product list page check which path use list.phtml file in magento 2